# MIUI How to disable badges on homescreen?

Tags: notifications, miui

MIUI uses those red badge notifications just like iOS, but I really want to disable them. Specifically for the MIUI Market, which I don't use because it's in Chinese (I only speak English). I have turned off all notifications in the market settings, and taken away every permission from Market within the system settings, but still the badges come up about once a day.

Any ideas?

Comment: By MIUI you're talking about http://miuiandroid.com/ just to confirm?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.